# move folder with files and subfolders with ExternalProject_Add_Step

Tags: cmake

I am using [`ExternalProject_Add_Step`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html). I want to move a folder with my source files and subfolders to another folder. However `ExternalProject_Add_Step` doesn't seem to accept ´*´.

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    MonoEngine
    copySource
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MONOENGINE_DIR}
    DEPENDEES createFolders
    COMMAND mv MonoEngineSource/* MonoEngine
    COMMENT "Moving src to MonoEngine folder"
)
```

It says `mv: cannot stat ‘MonoEngineSource/src/*’: No such file or directory`. If I replace the * with an existing file it works. But I want to move all the files and subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use CMake's cross-platform, [command-line tool mode](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) to achieve this:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    MonoEngine
    copySource
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MONOENGINE_DIR}
    DEPENDEES createFolders
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename MonoEngineSource MonoEngine
    COMMENT "Moving src to MonoEngine folder"
)
```

If the destination folder already exists you'll need to do this in two steps:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    MonoEngine
    copySource
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MONOENGINE_DIR}
    DEPENDEES createFolders
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory MonoEngineSource MonoEngine
    COMMENT "Copying src to MonoEngine folder"
)
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    MonoEngine
    removeSource
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MONOENGINE_DIR}
    DEPENDEES copySource
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory MonoEngineSource
    COMMENT "Removing MonoEngineSourcefolder"
)
```